# How to remove the OData innererror from production services

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, odata

The [spec for Error Response](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-json-format/v4.0/os/odata-json-format-v4.0-os.html#_Toc372793091) says:

> The value for the innererror name/value pair MUST be an object. The contents of this object are service-defined. Usually this object contains information that will help debug the service. The innererror name/value pair SHOULD only be used in development environments in order to guard against potential security concerns around information disclosure.

The spec is right, in asp.net the `innererror` property gives a useful info such as the stacktrace, but I really don't want to share this info with my API clients

As of yet, I haven't found a way of removing this property from the response, is it even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but is quite cumbersome.

You need to do four things:

Firstly, you should derive your own OData error serializer from the default implementation. The difference from the [default ODataErrorSerializer](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#OData/src/System.Web.OData/OData/Formatter/Serialization/ODataErrorSerializer.cs) will be to override the method containing the following code:

```
bool includeDebugInformation = oDataError.InnerError != null;
```

Change it to

```
bool includeDebugInformation = oDataError.InnerError == null;
```

or simply setting the value to `false` in your overridden implementation. Let's say your own OData error serializer is called `MyODataErrorSerializer`.

Then you need to derive your own OData serializer provider from the default one. The difference from the [DefaultODataSerializerProvider](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#OData/src/System.Web.OData/OData/Formatter/Serialization/DefaultODataSerializerProvider.cs) will be to change the following code:

```
private static readonly ODataErrorSerializer _errorSerializer = new ODataErrorSerializer();
```

to your own error serializer:

```
private static readonly ODataErrorSerializer _errorSerializer = new MyODataErrorSerializer();
```

Let's say your own serializer provider is called `MyODataSerializerProvider`.

After that, do the similar thing to `ODataMediaTypeFormatters`. Derive a `MyODataMediaTypeFormatters` from [DefaultODataMediaTypeFormatters](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#OData/src/System.Web.OData/OData/Formatter/ODataMediaTypeFormatters.cs) which uses `MyODataSerializerProvider` instead of `DefaultODataSerializerProvider`.

Finally, add the following code to your Web API OData implementation:

```
config.Formatters.InsertRange(0, ODataMediaTypeFormatters.Create());
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a way, but I do hope you plan to make it a lot easier in next versions. Doing so much work for a thing that is required by the spec for each and every written application is just wrong. Again, thanks.

Comment: @gdoron You're right. Let me surface this problem to the team and see if we can improve it.

Comment: While you are on it, please localize the error message and remove the debug information from the message. " The value for the message name/value pair MUST be a human-readable, language-dependent representation of the error. TheContent-Language header MUST contain the language code from [RFC5646] corresponding to the language in which the value for message is written."